# como compilar classes c++ no makefile?

Tags: c++

eu estava fazendo um programa em c++(normalmente ultilizava uma IDE pra poder compilar e tudo mais),porém desta vez necessitei fazê-lo sem uma IDE,enfim quando eu fiz o makefile para compilar o programa,ele deu um erro com algo relacionado ao construtor da classe

> g++ -c main.cpp g++ -c grafos.cpp In file included from grafos.cpp:1:0: /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Destroy(_Tp*) [with _Tp = Vertice]’: /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:103:19: required from ‘static void std::_Destroy_aux< >::__destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = Vertice*; bool  = false]’ /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:127:11: required from ‘void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = Vertice*]’ /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:151:15: required from ‘void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_T2>&) [with _ForwardIterator = Vertice*; _Tp = Vertice]’ /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:424:22: required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::~vector() [with _Tp = Vertice; _Alloc = std::allocator]’ grafos.cpp:3:14: required from here grafos.h:11:2: error: ‘Vertice::~Vertice()’ is private ~Vertice(); ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:62:0, from grafos.h:5, from grafos.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:93:7: error: within this context { __pointer->~_Tp(); } ^ makefile:15: recipe for target 'grafo.o' failed make: *** [grafo.o] Error 1

grafos.h

```
#ifndef GRAFOS_H
#define GRAFOS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Vertice{
private:
    ~Vertice();
    int valor;
    int peso;
    vector<Vertice> listaAdjArest;
};

class Grafo{
private:
    vector<Vertice> lista_v;
public:
    Grafo();
    ~Grafo();
    void InsereVertice(int valor);
    void InsereAresta(int valor,int peso);
    void ImprimirGrafo();
    void ImprimirTopologicamente();
    void ImprimirCaminhoCritico();
};

#endif
```

grafos.cpp

```
#include "grafos.h"

Grafo::Grafo()
{

}

Grafo::~Grafo(){

}

void Grafo::InsereVertice(int valor){

}

void Grafo::InsereAresta(int valor,int peso){

}

void Grafo::ImprimirGrafo(){

}

void Grafo::ImprimirTopologicamente(){

}

void Grafo::ImprimirCaminhoCritico(){

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "grafos.h"
#include "dados.h"

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

makefile

```
all:Executar limpar
Executar: main.o grafos.o dados.o
    g++ -Wall -o Projeto2 main.o grafos.o dados.o

main.o:main.cpp grafos.cpp grafos.h dados.cpp dados.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

grafos.o:grafos.cpp grafos.h
    g++ -c grafos.cpp

dados.o:dados.cpp dados.h
    g++ -c dados.cpp

limpar:
    rm -rf *.o
```

eu não sei ao certo oque está acontecendo com o programa,eu já tentei tirar algumas coisas do makefile,mas ainda continua tendo esse problema,também tentei pesquisar se existia um problema parecido,no entanto não consegui achar absolutamente nada,alguém sabe de alguma solução que possa fazer o makefile compilar os arquivos do C++ juntamente com as classes e os construtores?,quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço

OBS.:o link do git do programa,caso algum de vocês queiram testar para analisar melhor o problema https://github.com/RenanZX/Projeto2-Grafos , pode-se observar que o código está vazio, apenas foram definidas as classes e os métodos nas bibliotecas e mais nada

OBS2.:no c nunca tive este problema,compilei sem qualquer erro ou coisa do tipo,porém somente no c++ que está dando esse problema,e as IDE's compilam esse programa sem quaisquer problemas

Comment: Tem como colocar as partes relevantes do `main.cpp` e do `grafos.cpp`? Também creio que exista um `grafos.h` com dados relevantes

Comment: Ademais, normalmente quando se faz compilação parcial, normalmente ela é focada em um arquivo fonte por vez, não em dois. Normalmente há a presença de dois arquivos fontes para compilá-los juntos e gerar logo o executável, coisa que não veja na saída do erro

Comment: ja adicionei,inclusive inclui o makefile

Comment: eu acho que entendi oque você quis dizer,mas esse não é o problema em questão,na geração do arquivo .o,eu estou colocando tanto o arquivo .cpp de implementação quanto os cabeçalhos .h

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro, talvez tenha algo a ver com a declaração do destrutor de `Vertice` (`Vertice::~Vertice`) ser privado. Também não vi declaração do método no `.cpp` do respectivo _header_

Comment: não,não é,eu fiz uns testes aqui,e quando tirei tudo que tinha colocado com <vector>,ele funcionou! rodou numa boa,mas quando deixo o vector ele dá esse problema que você viu

Comment: eu coloquei o makefile que funcionou,oque resta é descobrir como compilar o <vector> usando o makefile

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema(mais simples do que eu imaginei),pra quem tiver o mesmo problema na hora da compilação,o `<vector>` é automaticamente destruído ao encerrar o programa quando é gerado,por isso o compilador estava acusando erros,por conta que na classe `Vertice` existia um destrutor `~Vertice()`,sendo que o próprio vector já possui um destrutor e isso estava gerando um conflito na hora da compilação